# Return ACL group of user

Tags: cakephp

I have created a user authentication system using cakephp's aco/aro tables using [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-use-cakephps-access-control-lists/).

I am now creating an interface to change the groups of users and display the current group of the user.

I searched the API and could not find a built-in method to query the group that a user belongs to. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You may or may not decide to do this but in my `users` table I have a `security_group_id` field that points to a `security_groups` table.  Within this `security_groups` table I store the aliases/names of the security groups (i.e. Administrators, Site Users, Managers, etc.).

In the `aro` table these security groups are root/parent nodes for all the subsequent user accounts that I create on the system.  Thus by querying my `users` tables `security_group_id` field, I can determine the group that the user is in.

Another approach would be to do:

```
$aro =& ClassRegistry::init('Aro');
$theUser = array('User' => array('id' => <user_id>));
$aroPath = $aro->node($theUser);
```

`$aroPath` will be an array including the user node in the `$aro` table as well as any and all parent nodes.